# Check whether a string appears in another in R

Tags: r, regex, string, compare

I've got a tibble containing sentences like that :

```r
df <- tibble(sentences = c("Bob is looking for something", "Adriana has an umbrella", "Michael is looking at..."))
```

And another containing a long list of names :

```r
names <- tibble(names = c("Bob", "Mary", "Michael", "John", "Etc."))
```

I would like to see if the sentences contain a name from the list and add a column to indicate if this is the case and get the following tibble :

```r
wanted_df <- tibble(sentences = c("Bob is looking for something", "Adriana has an umbrella", "Michael is looking at..."), check = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
```

So far I've tried that, with no success :

```r
df <- df %>%
mutate(check = grepl(pattern = names$names, x = df$sentences, fixed = TRUE))
```

And also :

```r
check <- str_detect(names$names %in% df$sentences)
```

Thanks a lot for any help ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should form a single regex expression in `grepl`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(check = grepl(paste(names$names, collapse = "|"), sentences))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  sentences                    check
  <chr>                        <lgl>
1 Bob is looking for something TRUE 
2 Adriana has an umbrella      FALSE
3 Michael is looking at...     TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
inx <- sapply(names$names, \(pat) grepl(pat, df$sentences))
inx
#>        Bob  Mary Michael  John  Etc.
#> [1,]  TRUE FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [2,] FALSE FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> [3,] FALSE FALSE    TRUE FALSE FALSE

inx <- rowSums(inx) > 0L
df$check <- inx
df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   sentences                    check
#>   <chr>                        <lgl>
#> 1 Bob is looking for something TRUE 
#> 2 Adriana has an umbrella      FALSE
#> 3 Michael is looking at...     TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

`grep` and family expect `pattern=` to be length 1. Similarly, `str_detect` needs *strings*, not a logical vector, and of the same length, so that won't work as-is.

We have a couple of options:

- `sapply` on the names (into a matrix) and see if each row has one or more matches:

  ```r
  df %>%
    mutate(check = rowSums(sapply(names$names, grepl, sentences)) > 0)
  # # A tibble: 3 × 2
  #   sentences                    check
  #   <chr>                        <lgl>
  # 1 Bob is looking for something TRUE 
  # 2 Adriana has an umbrella      FALSE
  # 3 Michael is looking at...     TRUE
  ```

  (I now see this is in RuiBarradas's answer.)
- Do a fuzzy-join on the data using `fuzzyjoin`:

  ```r
  df %>%
    fuzzyjoin::regex_left_join(names, by = c(sentences = "names")) %>%
    mutate(check = !is.na(names))
  # # A tibble: 3 × 3
  #   sentences                    names   check
  #   <chr>                        <chr>   <lgl>
  # 1 Bob is looking for something Bob     TRUE 
  # 2 Adriana has an umbrella      NA      FALSE
  # 3 Michael is looking at...     Michael TRUE
  ```

  This method as an advantage that it tells you which pattern (in `names`) made the match.

Comment: Thank you very much for these answers, it worked very well !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe we can try `adist` + `colSums` like below

```
df %>%
  mutate(check = colSums(adist(names$names, sentences, fixed = FALSE) == 0) > 0)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  sentences                    check
  <chr>                        <lgl>
1 Bob is looking for something TRUE
2 Adriana has an umbrella      FALSE
3 Michael is looking at...     TRUE
```